# Get scope object in restangular request interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular, angular-http-interceptors

I want to have a loading state for each resource object in an ng-repeat.  Restangulars addRequestInterceptor returns the element, but it doesn't seem to be linked to the angular $scope. Is there any way to get the $scope object from the arguments given?

```
Restangular.addRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, route, url){
    if (element){
        element.loading = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: The element argument in request interceptor is not DOM element, it is restangular element. It has nothing to do with DOM.

Comment: Yup as noted above interceptors are meant to operate on the data as it comes back or is in transit between two places (hence intercepted) but doesn't actually have to do with the DOM at all just data manipulation.  You probably want to use a service so you can inject the service into a directive or controller and update the loading value in the service from your interceptor.

Comment: Is there any other way to easily add a loading boolean for each element?  I'd like to do it for every model if possible.

Comment: You're really best off having a service that contains the loading data and then inject that service into all the controller that need to know something about the loading state (ones used with views where you want to show/hide loading display parts).  The alternative way to go is using events but personally I prefer having a service so there's a single point to debug all the stuff that's going on with regard to the loading state.  If you haven't seen it you may benefit from http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/ too.